# Dealing with metaclass conflict with SQL Alchemy declarative base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metaclass

I have a `class X` which derives from a class with its own metaclass `Meta`. I want to also derive X from the declarative base in SQL Alchemy. But I can't do the simple

```
def class MyBase(metaclass = Meta):
    #...

def class X(declarative_base(), MyBase):
    #...
```

since I would get metaclass conflict error:  'the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases'. I understand that I need to create a new metaclass that would derive from both Meta and from whatever metaclass the declarative base uses (DeclarativeMeta I think?). So is it enough to write:

```
def class NewMeta(Meta, DeclarativeMeta): pass
def class MyBase(metaclass = NewMeta):
    #...
def class X(declarative_base(), MyBase):
    #...
```

I tried this, and it **seems** to work; but I'm afraid I may have introduced some problem with this code.

I read the manual, but it's a bit too cryptic for me. What's

**EDIT:**

The code used for my classes is as follows:

```
class IterRegistry(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        attr['_registry'] = {}
        attr['_frozen'] = False
        print(name, bases)
        print(type(cls))
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._registry.values())

class SQLEnumMeta(IterRegistry, DeclarativeMeta): pass  

class EnumType(metaclass = IterRegistry):
    def __init__(self, token):
        if hasattr(self, 'token'):
            return
        self.token = token
        self.id = len(type(self)._registry)
        type(self)._registry[token] = self

    def __new__(cls, token):
        if token in cls._registry:
            return cls._registry[token]
        else:
            if cls._frozen:
                raise TypeError('No more instances allowed')
            else:
                return object.__new__(cls)

    @classmethod
    def freeze(cls):
        cls._frozen = True

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.token

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, token):
        return cls._registry[token]

class C1(Base, EnumType, metaclass = SQLEnumMeta):
    __tablename__ = 'c1'
    #...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Now having looked at `IterRegistry` and `DeclarativeMeta`, I think you're code is okay.

`IterRegistry` defines `__new__` and `__iter__`, while `DeclarativeMeta` defines `__init__` and `__setattr__`. Since there is no overlap, there's no direct need to call `super`. Nevertheless, it would good to do so, to future-proof your code.

---

Do you have control over the definition of `Meta`? Can you show us its definition? I don't think we can say it works or does not work unless we see the definition of `Meta`.

For example, there is a potential problem if your `Meta` does not call 
`super(Meta,cls).__init__(classname, bases, dict_)`

If you run this code

```
class DeclarativeMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print('DeclarativeMeta')
        # if '_decl_class_registry' in cls.__dict__:
        #     return type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)       
        # _as_declarative(cls, classname, dict_)
        return type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)

class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print('Meta')
        return type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)

class NewMeta(Meta,DeclarativeMeta): pass

class MyBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = NewMeta
    pass
```

Then only the string `'Meta'` gets printed.
In other words, only `Meta.__init__` gets run. `DeclarativeMeta.__init__` gets skipped.

On the other hand, if you define

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print('Meta')
        return super(Meta,cls).__init__(classname, bases, dict_)
```

Then both `Meta.__init__` and `DeclarativeMeta.__init__` gets run.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked that exact problem. I added the details in my question, but it seems things are getting way too complicated at this point..

Comment: Thanks. I am going to replace `return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)` with `return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)`. While not foolproof, at least it's a bit better than just hoping there's no `__new__` in Declarative Base. Certainly, all this multiple inheritance is very unsafe, since no one makes any precise contracts about behavior...

Comment: Multiple inheritance is generally ok (in Python). But multiple inheritance from classes that are instances of different metaclasses is hairy, with good reason (that's why there is a rule about explicitly merging metaclasses). We can understand what would mean for something to be a horse and a bird (even if we never saw one), but it's much harder to see what "being a horse and a good idea" could possibly mean. :-D